# Search dictionary keys with regex

Tags: python, dictionary

I have defined a dictionary with string keys:

```
{'dummy': 0, 'K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))': 1, 'K2::foo()': 2}
```

I want to search for key pattern (not the exact word), so `if 'foo' in my_dict:` should return true.

```
yax = 'foo'
if yax in my_dict:
    # Should definitely go here
    value = my_dict[yax]
    print(value)
else:
    # Just for error checking that the given name doesn't exist in dictionary
    print("Given value does not exist")
```

But the above code goes to the `else` section.

In the example, `foo` exists in two keys. That doesn't matter. the first match is OK. As another example, if I search for `bar`, the `if` statement should be true, too.

Comment: What you have shown isn't a Python dictionary.

Comment: Your dictionary is not valid python, please provide a reproducible object

Comment: I have updated the post. The values in the dictionary are dataframes.

Comment: The alternative to `my_dict.has_key('foo')` is `'foo' in my_dict` as you have already shown.

Comment: @mkrieger1: but it returns false. Please see the updated post.

Comment: Then `'foo'` is not a key of `my_dict`. Neither would `has_key('foo')` have returned `True` in Python 2.

Comment: @mkrieger1: As I said in the post, `foo` is key pattern, not the exact key string.

Comment: does `has_key` work with regex? I'm confused how this is related. Honestly I would define a regex `search_rgx` and then use something like `filter(my_dict.keys(), lambda k: not search_rgx.match(k) is None)` to receive the matching keys

Comment: Do you want to match foo as key or part of a key name?

Comment: @mozway: foo is part of the key string. If I search for bar, it should still return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, know that it is not a good approach to have to search through dictionary keys. The purpose of a dictionary is to enable O(1) access to the values using hashed keys.

That said, you can loop over the keys.

Searching any substring:

```
d = {'dummy': 0, 'K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))': 1, 'K2::foo()': 2}

[k for k in d if 'foo' in k]
```

Searching an independent word:

```
import re
[k for k in d if re.search(r'\bfoo\b', k)]
```

output: `['K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))', 'K2::foo()']`

##### as dictionary comprehension:

```
{k:v for k,v in d.items() if 'foo' in k}
```

output: `{'K1::foo(bar::z(x,u))': 1, 'K2::foo()': 2}`